__device__ call stack trace on CUDA
I'd like get call trace in a CUDA __device__ function, similar to backtrace. Is it possible to do that?

cuda-gdb has stack trace ability  see here slides 27-28

cuda-gdb has featured the ability to display stack traces for a least a decade.
You can use bt or info stack (I believe they are aliases) to print the call stack for the device thread which is the current focus of the debugger. Note that the device compiler can and will actively inline functions unless you explicitly ask it not to, and early hardware didn't support device side call frames or stack at all and
required all functions to be in-lined.
But if you have genuine __device__ functions called from within a kernel, you can examine the stack trace using cuda-gdb.
